# Is it possible to change the outfit characters wear in the story mode?

Tags: injustice-gods-among-us

I have a few outfits unlocked and was wondering if you could select outfits for the characters you play as during the story or if it's just for things like multiplayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible. If it were, some fight against the Regime [Hero] would be akward, as almost all cinematics.